# Get data horizontal in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, pivot, aggregate-functions

I have this query:

```
SELECT X, COUNT(*) AS TotalCount
FROM Table GROUP BY X, Y
ORDER BY X asc
```

It's returning:

```
X | Count
__________
A | 10
A | 11 
A |  1
B |  2
B |  5
B |  6
```

I'm trying to make it like this, if anyone could help me, thanks

```
X | Count1 | Count2 | Count3
A |  10    |   11   |  1
B |  2     |   6    |  5
```

Comment: Please show us the data you are starting from. What does `y` contain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pivot using conditional aggregation:

```
select x,
       sum(case when y = @val1 then 1 else 0 end),
       sum(case when y = @val2 then 1 else 0 end),
       sum(case when y = @val3 then 1 else 0 end)
from t
group by x;
```

It is unclear what the specific values are that go into each column.

Comment: Thank youuuu , you helped mee

Answer (score 2):

You would typically do this with conditional aggregation. Assuming that you want to order the columbs by `y`, you would also use window functions:

```
select x,
    max(case when rn = 1 then totalcount end) count1,
    max(case when rn = 2 then totalcount end) count2,
    max(case when rn = 3 then totalcount end) count3
from (
    select x, count(*) as totalcount,
        row_number() over(partition by x order by y) rn
    from mytable 
    group by x, y 
) t
order by x
```